# regex match for words with spaces in between them

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex pattern `([^\s|:]+):\s*([^\s|:]+)` which works well for `name:jones|location:london|age:23`. How can I extend the regex pattern to cover spaced words having space between them or words combined with numbers, for example: `full name:jones hardy|city and dialling code :london 0044|age:23 years`

```
>>> ("full name", "jones hardy") ("city and dialling code", "london 0044")("age","23 years")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your regex, to capture everything except the delimiter which in your case is colon `:` or pipe `|`

```
>>> r = r"([^:|]+)\s*:\s*([^:|]+)"
>>> st = "full name:jones hardy|city and dialling code :london 0044"
>>> re.findall(r, st)
[('full name', 'jones hardy'), ('city and dialling code ', 'london 0044')]
>>> st="name:jones|location:london|age:23"
>>> re.findall(r, st)
[('name', 'jones'), ('location', 'london'), ('age', '23')]
```

Answer (score 2):

This situation seems like it calls for `re.split`.

```
>>> s = "full name:jones hardy|city and dialling " \
...     "code :london 0044|age:23 years"
>>> [tuple(re.split('\s*:\s*', t))
...  for t in re.split('\s*\|\s*', s)]
[('full name', 'jones hardy'),
 ('city and dialling code', 'london 0044'),
 ('age', '23 years')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s= "full name:jones hardy|city and dialling code :london 0044|age:23 years"
>>> r=r"([^|:]+?)\s*:\s*([^|:]+)"
>>> re.findall(r, s)
[('full name', 'jones hardy '), ('city and dialling code', 'london 0044'), ('age', '23 years')]
```

So, the space at the end of `'city and dialling code '` will be eliminated.

But if there are spaces beforce `'|'`, it will not be eliminated:

```
>>> s="full name:jones hardy |city and dialling code :london 0044|age:23 years"
>>> re.findall(r, s)
[('full name', 'jones hardy '), ('city and dialling code', 'london 0044'), ('age', '23 years')]
```

The will be a space at the end of `'jones hardy '`.

### EDIT

`r"\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*:\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*(?:\||$)"` will eliminate all spaces at the begin and the end of the target string:

```
>>> s
'  full name: jones hardy | city and dialling code :london 0044|age:23 years'
>>> r=r"\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*:\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*(?:\||$)"
>>> re.findall(r, s)
[('full name', 'jones hardy'), ('city and dialling code', 'london 0044'), ('age', '23 years')]
```